# What's the difference between SciTE4AutoIt3's Build and Compile options?

Tags: build, compilation, autoit, scite

In SciTE4AutoIt3's `Tools` menu I can choose `Build` or `Compile`.

What's the difference? They both create an .exe file.

Answer (score 4):

A build is series of steps which usually include:

1. Compilation
2. Updating of Version information
3. Inclusion of resources and manifest information.

For AutoIt, using the SciTE editor, Compile and Build are almost the same. The only difference is that Compile presents you with a GUI where you can alter compile settings, such as which packages to include. Build will just run Compile with default settings.